# Simple Java program producing no output on Eclipse EE IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to execute a simple Java program in newly setup Eclipse IDE, but cannot see any output in console. Below is my program

```
/** 
 * The HelloWorldApp class implements an application that
 * simply prints "Hello World!" to standard output.
 */
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

Have checked build paths for JRE and JDK is added to environment variables as well. I am missing some configuration settings but not able to figure that out. Any leads will be helpful.

---

Compilation is working perfectly file and .classes work as expected via cmd.
Added a breakpoint in the main method. When I did debug As -> application, error is thrown, its not able to launch the class.

Error Thrown --> Cannot connect to VM
           Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking

Comment: Is there any error? Did you choose correct main function when running?

Comment: Strange! First check on command prompt whether you have java installed or not. Eclipse should not give any issues if java is installed properly. Put a breakpoint inside main and see if control comes there.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen There is only 1 main function in above code. I just did Run As -> Java Application on Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @DivyeshKalbhor Java is installed and configured and I can use it via cmd. Interstingly, I added a breakpoint and looks like the program did not enter the main function after few seconds the terminated message is shown:

Comment: This looks funny to me! Can you take the same .java file outside and then compile it into a class file and check the output? Use cmd prompt for this and not eclipse. The class you have looks absolutely fine.

Comment: One more thing is : Check the class file generated by eclipse. Whether the class file is generated or not? If yes, try running that file directly from cmd prompt.

Comment: Works perfectly fine from cmd and output as expected.

Comment: Executed the .class created by Eclipse. It also works via cmd.

Comment: Ohh! This means the eclipse is working fine but somehow it is not able to pick the class file during run time! I am not sure why this is happening, may be an issue with eclipse and try creating another class may be just to check or reopen eclipse and check, at last reinstall!

Comment: Clean the project and run the right one..

Comment: @DivyeshKalbhor Tried reinstalling eclipse but no luck.
Tested creating new projects and different classes but still cannot see the output.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small pull-down icon on the right of the console that lets you select which console you want to see. Maybe you accidentally selected a different console.

If this doesn't work try next.

Go to `run` and choose `Run Configurations -> Common` and in the Standard Input and Output configuration see if `Allocate Console` is selected.

[image]

Comment: Correct console is selected.
Allocate console is also checked.

Comment: More details added to the issue based on whatever debugged so far.